# tableview reload not calling the tableview delegate methods

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

[image]I have a tableview in TrendingEventsTableViewController class and a selectRadiusViewController that implements a picker view. Upon selction of a value from the pickerview the data on TrendingEventsTableViewController should reload with the new data from ParseModelClass. When NSlogged to check, none of the tableview delegate methods are called after tableview reloaddata.

```
//pickerview method of selectRadiusViewController

    -(void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    NSString *result = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Radius Chosen is %@", Radii[row]];


    self.RadiusChosen.text=result;

    ParseDataModel *obj = [[ParseDataModel alloc]init];
    TrendingListViewController *tobj = [[TrendingListViewController alloc]init];
   tobj.RadiusInput = true ;// ** true indicates table view should be modified
    [obj CalRadius:6000]; // call this method to populate modified array
    NSLog(@"Contrl returned after calRad func call with count: %lu", obj.modEventNames.count);


   // dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [tobj.TrendingTableView reloadData];
   //});

}

//callRadius method in ParseDataModelClass to get the new data to refresh the tableview

-(void) CalRadius:(int) rad

{  
    CLLocation *Userlocation = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:57.052443 longitude:9.910623];

    PFGeoPoint *ULocation =  [[PFGeoPoint alloc]init];
    ULocation.latitude=57.052443;
    ULocation.longitude=9.910623;

    // PFGeoPoint *ULocation =[PFGeoPoint geoPointWithLatitude:40.75060000 longitude:73.99360000];

    self.GeoPointsRadii = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    self.modEventNames =  [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

  //  --------<filtering radius array >---------

    PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"EventInfo"];
    [query whereKey:@"EventLocation" nearGeoPoint:ULocation withinKilometers:6000];

     self.GeoPointsRadii = [query findObjects];

    for(int i=0; i< [ self.GeoPointsRadii  count] ; i++)
    {

            PFObject *tempObj = self.GeoPointsRadii [i];
            self.modEventNames[i]=tempObj[@"EventName"];

    }

  }

//TrendingEventsTableViewController

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    NSLog(@"No of sections called");
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    NSLog(@"numberOfRowsInSection called");

    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    if(self.RadiusInput==false)
    return self.myGuys.count;
    else{
        ParseDataModel *obj=[[ParseDataModel alloc]init];
       return  obj.modEventNames.count;
    }
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSLog(@"TABLE VIEW method called");

      static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell"; // reuse identifier

    // check if we can reuse a cell from row that just went off screen
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    // create new cell, if needed
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    if(self.RadiusInput==false)
    {
        NSLog(@"TABLE VIEW FILLING NORMALLY WITH myGuys");
    UIImage *image= [UIImage imageNamed:@"garfield(1).jpg"];
    cell.imageView.image= image;
    // set text attibute of cell
    cell.textLabel.text = [self.myGuys objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }

    else{
        NSLog(@"TABLE VIEW RELOADING");

        UIImage *image= [UIImage imageNamed:@"garfield(1).jpg"];
        cell.imageView.image= image;
        // set text attibute of cell
        ParseDataModel *obj=[[ParseDataModel alloc]init];

        cell.textLabel.text = [obj.modEventNames objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }
    // set accessory type to standard detail disclosure indicator
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Just making sure, did you set <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource> ? Also, did you make sure the reloadData method is actually being called?

Comment: @RoyKronenfeld Yes, I did

Comment: @interface TrendingListViewController : UITableViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource>

Comment: Do you tobj.TrendingTableView.delegate = self when you create the table?

Comment: I just have the datasource and delegate set on the story board to TrendingViewController

Comment: Any chance for screenshots?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97103/discussion-between-askatral-and-roy-kronenfeld).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In oder to reload the table from a different class you may use *NSNotification* to let the view controller of the table know when to reloadData.

In the view controller of the table, under viewDidLoad, add this:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:@"reloadData" object:nil];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(reloadTable:) name:@"reloadData" object:nil];
```

Add this method as well in the table view controller:

```
- (void)reloadTable:(NSNotification *)notification { 
    [self.TrendingTableView reloadData]; 
}
```

Lastly, in the picker view controller fire the notification (instead of `[tobj.TrendingTableView reloadData];`):

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"reloadData" object:self];
```

Comment: @askatral My pleasure!